# How pip manages same packages over different environments for space efficiency

Tags: python, pip

I am using a huge pip environment `env1`, and I would like to create a new one (`env2`) that only has one different package, the rest is the same as `env1`.

Is it necessary to reinstall all packages again in `env2`?
Will it take the same space in my hard drive as `env1` or pip manages automatically the space efficiency via something like symbolic links for same packages over all environments?

My objective is to reduce the space that takes the second environment as much as possible.

---

Just in case I created the environments with:

```
python3 -m venv env1
python3 -m venv env2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it necessary to reinstall all packages again in env2?

Yes.

> Will it take the same space in my hard drive as env1

Yes.

> or pip manages automatically the space efficiency

No. There is no way to symlink from other environments because they could be different — different Python versions, different package versions, different compilation flags.

Another problem: how would `pip` find `env1` from `env2`? `pip` doesn't track existing environments, they could be anywhere.

Yet another problem: what you gonna do in env `env2` if you delete `env1`? The symlinks in `env2` would become dangling.

Short resume: disk space is cheaper than solving major problems from trying to manage space.

Comment: Does Conda function the same way? Maybe if it has this functionality I can use it instead.

Comment: No idea, never used (ana)conda. But I doubt it can do that.